# Stacked Bar Chart with multiple variables in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to make a stacked bar chart from this data table:

| Amino Acid | Agaricus bisporus | Aspergillus nidulans | Bipolaris maydis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CYS | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ASP | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GLU | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| PHE | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GLY | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| HIS | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ILE | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| LYS | 10 | 7 | 16 |
| LEU | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| MET | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ASN | 9 | 15 | 15 |
| PRO | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| GLN | 11 | 13 | 4 |
| ARG | 13 | 16 | 21 |
| SER | 11 | 13 | 8 |
| THR | 9 | 11 | 9 |
| VAL | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| TRP | 8 | 7 | 6 |
| TYR | 9 | 6 | 7 |

I want the barchart to look like this:
[image: Stacked Bar chart]
I need the colours to represent the different Amino acids.

When I use the default plot setting this is what I get

[image]

Comment: May be you can see this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449462/stacked-barplot-with-some-customizations-using-matplotlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a stacked barplot via pandas, each of the columns will be converted to a layer of bars. The index of the dataframe will be used as the x-axis.

In the given dataframe, you seem to want the columns for the x-axis. Using `.T` to transpose the dataframe (exchanging rows and columns), will help. First, you'll need to set the amino acids as index.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654486/stacked-bar-chart-with-multiple-variables-in-python')[0]

ax = df.set_index('Amino Acid').T.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0, cmap='tab20', figsize=(10, 7))
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: stacked bar plot from transposed dataframe]

Comment: Thank you so much! I sort of got that I needed to swap the rows and columns but couldn't get how. I tried to melt the data frame but that didn't work.