# matplotlib stacked barplot remove gaps in columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stacked

I want to create a matplotlib stacked barplot with ordered values. However, this is the result I got:
[image: Gap in stacked barplot column]

I want to remove those gaps from the column, bit idk how to do it. Here is the code that I've used:

```
val1 = [ 2.20810623,  9.1243303,   9.78813997, 11.19015164, 13.71907402, 16.07695801,
 20.60492477, 23.69439942, 25.23510585, 29.3574946 ]
val2 = [70.6425054,  74.76489415, 76.30560058, 79.39507523, 83.92304199, 86.28092598,
 88.80984836, 90.21186003, 90.8756697,  97.79189377]

ax.bar(x=df[df['team'] == 'A']['source'], height=val1, label = "A")
ax.bar(x=df[df['team'] == 'A']['source'], height=val2, label = "B",bottom=val1)
for bar in ax.patches:
  ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
          bar.get_height() / 2 + bar.get_y(),
          round(bar.get_height()), ha = 'center',
          color = 'w', weight = 'bold', size = 10)
ax.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_ylabel('percentage')
```

Comment: There are just so many posts on how to create stacked bar plots ([here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654486/stacked-bar-chart-with-multiple-variables-in-python)), why trying to reinvent the wheel? ;)

Comment: how does your x look like?

Comment: it seems team B is ordered in reverse. but you pick the bottom values of team.

Comment: Your x-values and both of `val1` and `val2` need all be sorted together. You can't sort them separately.  Also note that your x-values shouldn't have duplicates to avoid multiple bars plotted at the same spot. Apart from missing x-values, the code in your post is not the source of the plot shown. Did you reverse both arrays in your second call to `ax. Bar()`?